# hide instance not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We do not appear (yes/No) for hide instance in SSCM for all SQL Server 2012 servers.

We are unable to see (yes/No) option for hide instance . Kindly assist me here .

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

This is the procedure: [Hide an Instance of SQL Server Database Engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/hide-an-instance-of-sql-server-database-engine)

Is the SQL Server Browser running?

The information to hide or show the instance is stored in registry. You can use extended stored procedure `xp_instance_regwrite` to update the registry value to hide or show the instance. Below T-SQL will hide the instance. To unhide instance set @value to 0 :

```
EXEC master..xp_instance_regwrite
  @rootkey = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
  @key =
N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib',
  @value_name = N'HideInstance',
  @type = N'REG_DWORD',
  @value = 1
  — 0 = No, 1 = Yes
```

To check if an instance is hidden you can use `xp_instance_regread` to check registry values:

```
DECLARE @getValue INT
EXEC master..xp_instance_regread
  @rootkey = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
  @key=
N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib',
  @value_name = N'HideInstance',
  @value = @getValue OUTPUT
SELECT @getValue
```

This method only prevents the instance from being listed on the network. It does not prevent users from connecting to server if they know the instance name.